# ¿Por qué no se aplica el filtro del <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, html-select

Buen dia. Tengo mi fragmento de codigo html:

```
<select id="stateSelect">
       <option value="all">All States</option>
</select>
```

Y el codigo js:

```
    //Creando el array con los miembros via JSON
let membersArray = data.results[0].members;
//Incrustando en una variable el id del select
let selectStates = document.getElementById ("stateSelect");
//Creando un array de estados
let states = [];
membersArray.forEach (member => {
    if (!states.includes(member.state)) {
        states.push (member.state);
    }
});
states.sort();
//Creando los elementos para trabajar con estados
states.forEach (state => {
    let option = document.createElement ("option");
    option.innerText = state;
    option.value = state;
    selectStates.appendChild (option);
})
//Creando la funcion para llenar la tabla
function fillTable (array, idTable) {
    let tableToFill = document.getElementById(idTable);
    tableToFill.innerHTML = "";
    if (array.length == 0) {
        let row = document.createElement ("tr");
        row.innerHTML = `<td colspan="5">Select at least One filter to apply</td>`
        tableToFill.appendChild (row);
    }
    array.forEach(member => {
        let row = document.createElement ("tr");
        row.innerHTML = `<td><a href = "${member.url}"> ${member.first_name} ${member.middle_name || ""} ${member.last_name}</a></td><td>${member.party}</td><td>${member.state}</td><td>${member.seniority}</td><td>${member.votes_with_party_pct}%</td>`;
        tableToFill.appendChild (row);
    });
}
fillTable (membersArray, "tableData");
//Creando los eventos
let formFiltros = document.getElementById("formFilter");
formFiltros.addEventListener ("change", (e) => {

    let checkboxes = formFiltros.querySelectorAll ("[type='checkbox']");
    let checkeds = Array.from (checkboxes).filter (checkbox => checkbox.checked);
    let selectedParty = checkeds.map (checkbox => checkbox.value);
    let selectedS = selectStates.value;
    let filteredList = filterStateCheckboxes (membersArray, selectedS, selectedParty);
    fillTable (filteredList, "tableData");
});
//Esta funcion deberia comprobar el estado de los checkboxes y del select (el select es el cual no toma al momento del click)
function filterStateCheckboxes (member, state, party) {
    let filterMember = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < member.length; index++) {
        if (member[index].state == state || state == "all") {
            if (party.includes(member[index].party)) {
                filterMember.push (member[index]);
            }
        } 
    }
    return filterMember;
}
```

La idea es que, al marcar en un estado de los Estados Unidos, muestre a quienes viven en dicho estado reflejado en una tabla. El punto es que dicha seleccion no ocurre ni aparece el problema en consola tampoco.
El filtro por partido (checkboxes) funciona bien, el , no.

Espero puedan darme una mano, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca definiste la variable selectStates, no veo niguna llamada de tu elemento select, hiciste esto:

```
selectStates.appendChild(option);
```

pero antes de eso tienes que hacer esto:

```
var selectStates = document.getElementById('stateSelect');
```

Comment: Si, perdon, lo hice mas arriba pero no pegue todo el codigo para que no fuese muy largo.

Comment: Ahora si coloce el codigo completo del js para su mayor entendimiendo. Gracias por tu respuesta.